# Subscrate Dates and convert to the Format DD:HH:MM:SS Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I am facing a problem where I need to add seconds to a date and then subtract the current date to get the remaining time for the update to be completed.

I can use a hidden input to get the value from the database using jQuery. I would therefore have a hidden input with the value of create_at date, under the format `2015-09-10 14:44:24 UTC` and a hidden input with the time in seconds ex: `86400 => 1Day` the update takes to be completed.

How can I, using rails, jQuery & js to get the value under the format D:HH:MM:SS left for to update to be completed.

**Concrete Question**: How can I add `86340` seconds to the `2015-09-10 14:44:24 UTC` to get a new date (update finish time) and then get the current time at UTC and "subtract" that from the update finish time to get the time left for the update to finish and then convert that to the format DD:HH:MM:SS.

Let me know if I am not clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moment.js to the rescue
http://momentjs.com/

```
var dateString = moment('2015-09-10 14:44:24 UTC')
  .add(86400, 's')
  .format('DD:HH:MM:SS');
// hope i understood your request correctly
```

moment has a bunch of helpful methods for manipulating dates.

alternatively you can convert all dates to ms and manipulate them as integers.

Comment: How can I subtract the current datetime to the date I get after adding 86400 s to the initial date. So that I can get time left for the update to be completed.